# Is a closed set in the subspace topology always closed in the space topology?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $(X, \tau)$ a topological space. If $Y \in \tau$, then
>
> 1. $E \in \tau_Y \implies E \in \tau$
> 2. $E \in \tau_Y^\star \implies E \in \tau^\star$

The first point was very easy to prove, but I think the second one isn't even true. I have proved that if $E$ is a closed set in $\tau_Y^\star$, then it's the intersection of $Y$ and a closed set in $\tau^\star$. But from this I cannot prove that $E$ itself is a closed set in $\tau^\star$.

I think I have found a counterexample. Consider the space $(\mathbb R, \mathcal E_1)$. Let $Y = (0, 2)$ be an open set with respect to the euclidean topology. Then $E = Y \cap [-1, 1] = (0, 1]$ is a closed set in $\tau_Y^\star$, but it's not closed in $\mathcal E_1^\star$.

Is my reasoning correct and the exercise wrong? To make the exercise correct I think that one must let $Y \in \tau$ in point $1)$ and $Y \in \tau^\star$ in point $2)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: More easily $Y$ is closed in its own topology  but it usually is not closed in $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. An even easier example is obtained just taking $Y$ itself (which is always in $\tau^\ast_Y$).

What is true: $$Y \in \tau \text{ iff } \forall U \subseteq Y: U \in \tau_Y \rightarrow U \in \tau$$

and

$$Y \in \tau^\ast \text{ iff } \forall U \subseteq Y: U \in \tau^\ast_Y \rightarrow U \in \tau^\ast$$